# If $P(A) = 100$ and $P(B) = 100$, how can I find $P(A \cap B)$ without $P(A \cup B)$?

Tags: probability

Logically it seems obvious that $P(A \cup B)$ will be 100, but is that valid enough reason?

Comment: Do you really mean *one hundred*, cause that's a little too big to be a probability...

Comment: Assuming you meant $P(A)=P(B)=1$, note that $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(A\cap B) \Longrightarrow P(A\cup B) + P(A\cap B) = 2.$$ Since probabilities are always in $[0,1]$, it must be that $P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B) = 1$.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to answer on the assumption that you *meant* that

$$ P(A) = P(B) = 1 $$

In this case, observe that $A \subset A \cup B $, so

$$ P(A) \leq P(A \cup B) $$

But also

$$ P(A \cup B) \leq 1 $$

by virtue of being a probability.  Using that $ P(A) = 1 $, this puts us in the following situation

$$ 1 \leq P(A \cup B) \leq 1 $$

So the value of $P(A \cup B)$ is forced on us.  You can take it from here to get $P(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take it intuitively we know that both A and B must be in the sample space and the total probability of the sample space is 1 (i.e) **P(S) = 1**

It is given that **P(A)=P(B)=1** (assuming u meant 1 cause it can't be 100).

So we have that both **P(A)** and **P(B)** must occupy the same space/region (i.e) they completely overlap each other because their probability can't be more than that of the sample space.

since they overlap each other **P(A∩B)=P(AUB)=1**.

we can conclude that **P(A)=P(B)=P(A∩B)=P(AUB)=P(S)=1**

Comment: please improve formatting